# Implement Favicon

Tags: html, favicon

I want to implement a favicon and use this line in my index.html:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something else? It doesn't show me an icon in all browsers.

Comment: try a full link not a relative one or place it on the website root (no modifications needed at the index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my expirance,

1. Probably you need to poot it in root folder of your site
2. Refresh of your page msy be required (cnrl+f5)

Also, i think it should be "valid" icon (not renamed jpg...).